# Output an object to the Logcat console

Tags: android, logging

I would like to take a look at an object, similar to a `print_r(an_object)` in php, or a `console.log(an_object)` in javascript (in browser), but for Android.

I tried this

```
public void a_method( SomeClass the_arg )
{ 
    Log.d( "an_id" , the_arg );
}
```

This generates an error message:

> Error:(23, 10) error: no suitable method found for d(String,View)
>   method Log.d(String,String,Throwable) is not applicable
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>   method Log.d(String,String) is not applicable
>   (actual argument View cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You cannot print an object to the console in Java as you would in javascript.

You have three solutions.

1) Use debugger. Place a breakpoint and debug in android studio. Then you can inspect the full object in scope.

2) Serialize your object (for example to JSON) and print the result to console.

3) Override `toString` method of your object to give you all the information you want and call `Log.d("myTag", yourObj.toString())`

I highly recommend first method. I used to avoid Debugger but learning how to use the debugger was the best thing I did. It increases your efficiency and makes debugging super easy

Comment: I marked this as the answer because it tells me that my javascript-thinking must change (`You cannot print an object to the console in Java as you would in javascript.`), and it gives severaloptions

Comment: For option 3, beware the NullPointerException

Comment: Very good point @cricket_007 if you're expecting `yourObj` to be null at any point. If `yourObj` should never be null, I tend to not null check and let the application crash. Then I can track the reason behind the obj being null.

Comment: That's why I use `String.valueOf` on values I'm unsure about. That returns null as a String instead of crashing

Comment: 2 is the best, thank you. Did it with `JSON.stringify(someObject)`.

Answer (score 10):

Convert object to JSON. You can use Gson.

```
val gson = Gson()
val json = gson.toJson(yourObject)
Log.e(TAG, json)
```

Or

```
Log.e(TAG, Gson().toJson(yourObject))
```

Answer (score 6):

The second argument must be a String.

```
Log.d("an_id", String.valueOf(the_arg));
```

Your error says you can't log a `View` class

> no suitable method found for d(String,View)

Don't be surprised when you see some nonsense in the console when you print that `View` object through using `String.valueOf`

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit easy to output the data object in the logcat.

The correct way is to `override` the `toString()` inside the object. 
It can be generated by the Android Studio itself by following this simple steps:

1- Open the DataClass

2- Press Alt+Insert OR right click and click on `Generate...`

3- In Generate window select `toString()`

4- Select all the variables in the next window and click `OK`

5- `toString()` method would `override` in your data class returning the `String` template of your data model.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Gson class as shown below :

```
public void yourMethod(SomeClass theObject) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Log.d( "sample" , gson.toJson(theObject));
}
```

Here is its Gradle repository
`implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'`

Answer (score 0):

just wrote one generic method, which makes it possible trough reflection:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Field field : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        String item;
        if(! field.getType().getSimpleName().equals("ArrayList")) {
            try {
                Object value = field.get(this);
                item = String.format("%s %s %s: %s%n", Modifier.toString(field.getModifiers()), field.getType().getSimpleName(), field.getName(), String.valueOf(value));
                sb.append(item);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            item = String.format("%s %s %s: ArrayList<>%n", Modifier.toString(field.getModifiers()), field.getType().getSimpleName(), field.getName());
            sb.append(item);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```